# Matching two databases and insert same rows to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

I have 2 databases named DB1 and DB2 with a table called `movies`. `movie` contains `movie_name`, `year`, `synopsis`, `AKA` etc. As you can see `synopsis` and `AKA` columns are empty. I want to match two columns (`movie_name` and `year`) and insert identical results into DB1's empty columns.

**DB1.movies**

```
movie_name | year | synopsis | AKA
----------------------------------------
titanic    | 1997 |          |
matrix     | 1999 |          |
alien      | 1979 |          |
```

**DB2.movies**

```
movie_name | year | synopsis | AKA
----------------------------------------
titanic    | 1997 | xxxxxxx  | XXX
matrix     | 1999 | yyyyyyy  | YYY
alien      | 1979 | zzzzzzz  | ZZZ
```

After then, DB1.movies should look like this:

**DB1.movies**

```
movie_name | year | synopsis | AKA
----------------------------------------
titanic    | 1997 | xxxxxxx  | XXX
matrix     | 1999 | yyyyyyy  | YYY
alien      | 1979 | zzzzzzz  | ZZZ
```

What can I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are DB1 and DB2 really TABLES and movie_name, year, synopsis, AKA fields on those tables?  Your terminology doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're right Mike. I could not fully explain. There are tables on different DBs.

Comment: Are they different DB on the same server?

Comment: Yes, different DB on same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2 on db1.table1.movie_name = db2.table2.movie_name AND db1.table1.year = db2.table2.year SET db1.table1.synopsis = db2.table2.synopsis, db1.table2.AKA = db2.table2.AKA
```

Note I didn't know the table names for the tables in db1 and db2, so I just called them table1 and table2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks. But I have films with same names. I want to do matching of using the 'year' table.

Comment: I have updated the original answer to reflect the join being made across both the film name and year now.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm going to assume that the tables are called `movies` in each database.)

If you want to replace the data with movies in DB2 (and the tables in both databases have matching primary keys), then you can do the following:

```
replace into db1.movies select * from db2.movies
```

If you just want to update the `synonpsis` and `AKA` fields within existing rows, do:

```
update db1.movies mov1, db2.movies mov2
   set mov1.synopsis   = mov2.synopsis,
       mov1.AKA        = mov2.AKA
 where mov1.movie_name = mov2.movie_name
```